# Display Django model entries as part of a form

Tags: django, forms

I want to display model entries as part of a form so I can update them. What is the best way to do this? I am using crispy forms.

I first filter my object, and then I want to display this object as a form, where certain model attributes are display only, with some attributes being updated.

Essentially a table containing all attributes for obj that cant be modified, with 2 attributes that will be updated in the form.

forms.py:

```
class ReportSampleForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReportSampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        sample = self.data.get('sample_id', False)
        obj = VariantAnnotationSampleRun.objects.filter(sample_run_id=sample)

        self.helper = FormHelper()

        self.fields['id'] = forms.ChoiceField(
                required=True,
                label='blah:',
                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                choices=((s.id, (s.variant_annotation_id.variant_id, s.attribute1, s.attribute2)) for s in obj)
            )

        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
```

This displays check boxes with variant_id, attribute1 and attribute2, but I would like Model entries 'evidence' and 'annotation' to be filled in and if the checkbox is checked and form submitted, the database gets updated for that specific model entry.

models.py:

class VariantAnnotationSampleRun(models.Model):

```
    variant_annotation_id = models.ForeignKey(VariantAnnotation,
    attribute1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    attribute2 = models.IntegerField()

    reported = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    evidence = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    annotation = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
```

Is this possible to do without building a totally bespoke form, from my view?

Answer (score 0):

Use a ModelForm, select the model entry you want to use in it and create an instance of that form.

```
class MyModel (models.Model):
   ...


class MyForm (forms.ModelForm):
   model = MyModel


def my_view(request):
   obj = myModel.objects.get(id=1)
   variables = {}
   variables['form'] = myForm(instance=obj)
   render (request, 'mypage.html', variables)
```

Then in mypage.html include `{{ form }}` wherever you want it.